# Selenium Test проверка

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

Здравствуйте. У меня есть такое вот задание, есть сайт, мне нужно с помощью Selenium test проверить подгрузку контента  при прокрутке  странички вниз. Скажите как это написать в коде? Какой он должен быть этот код приблизительно? Гуглил по запросу selenium webdriver scroll , но толком ничего не нашел. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Можно скроллить средствами JavaScript - вызовом `window.scroll`:

```
public static void ScrollDown(WebDriver driver)
{
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.scroll(0, 350);");
}
```

<sub>взято с [How to recognize scrollbar and scroll up/down using Selenium2, C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177362/how-to-recognize-scrollbar-and-scroll-up-down-using-selenium2-c-sharp)</sub>

Comment: о, то что надо но как еще при этом проверить подгрузку контента, по id блоков или как?

Comment: @M-Misha-M - да как при любом ajax - `WebDriverWait` с таймаутом

Comment: извини я мало понял что то с твоих слов, так как не изучали толком эту технологию, а тут дали вот так с потолка задание, можна пожалуйста поконкретнее

Comment: Имелось ввиду примерно так: wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5) wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "id"))) , можно и не по id, конечно или не кликабельность проверять, а что-то что Вам больше подходит. Техника проста: скроллим страницу, ждём появления элементов, скроллим далее. Если нужные элементы не появились - ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Скроллил через [Locatable](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/internal/Locatable.html): (пройдите по ссылке)

```
 ((Locatable) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="sidebar"]/div[5]/div/div[7]/a[2]")).getCoordinates();
```

Locatable скроллит к нужной элементу, т.е. вы его указываете id элемента.

Answer (score 0):

1. `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`
2. Зацикливаем проверку нахождения элемента
3. `boolean elemIsDisplayed = false`
4. `while (!elemIsDisplayed)`
5. Скроллим как написано выше
6. `try { driver.findElement(By.ТипЛокатора(ваш локатор)).isDisplayed() }`
7. `elemIsDisplayed = true`
8. Элемент найден
9. `finally { Элемент не найден }`